# Pause blinker after amount of time

Tags: javascript, time

So I get my text blinking and would I like it to stop after a few seconds.

Here is a [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ2L5/82/) where I would like to change the mouse enter action with a timer or something, but I don't know what.

```js
var p = $("p");

p.blinker({
  timeHidden: 50,
  intervalRangeStart: 100,
  intervalRangeStop: 500
});

p.bind("mouseenter", function(){
  $(this).data("blinker").pause();
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #111;
    padding: 50px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

p {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello there!</p>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly. So, your fiddle currently pauses the blinking **immediately** upon `mouseenter`. Yet, you want to include a timer that pauses the blinking (for example) 10 seconds after `mouseenter`. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

You could use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $(this).data("blinker").pause();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks gabesoft for your response! I was sure it was something doing with a setTimeout but I was struggling because there were not only one `<p>` element…! Here is the code working fine (with the jQuery blinker addon):

```js
$("p").blinker({
  timeHidden: 25,
  intervalRangeStart: 50,
  intervalRangeStop: 200
})

setTimeout(function() {
  $(p).each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).data("blinker").pause();
  });
}, 2000);
```